# VS 2012 Install Shield Installer SQL Compact

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

Good evening!

Here is the thing, i've been trying to create a setup project for my app which includes some winforms and a SQL Compact Data Base.

I already added to my VS 2012 the required installation to create install shield installers for my apps, i add it to my project and i follow the instructions.

Once im asked to add the required files to their destination computer paths i add on the install directory the interface final results and to a C:\ folder, the data base final results. I of course changed the database connection to that new folder.

I proceed to generate the installation and then use it on my own computer, everything goes smooth, and once it finishes, i launch the app, it works okay, but upon opening a form which has a datagridview inside of it (or i click a button that has a connection with the database) i get an error messagge telling me that the db files could not be found.

I go to the database folder and it is there, but it doesnt work, the thing is, if i go to my VS 2012 projects folder, open the DataBase project folder and i copy the database inside of it (.sdf file) and i paste it in the new folder for the program, the app works just fine.

Any suggestions? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you putting the database file on the root of the system disk? This is not a place where a READ/WRITE file should be located. Permissions usually forbids to a normal user this kind of access.

Comment: Sorry, it was kind of confusing how i wrote it down, the database file is inside a folder on C:\ , for example C:\DataBase\database.sdf